# Como exportar correctamente un div a pdf con html2canvas

Tags: javascript

Estoy usando html2canvas junto con la librería pdfmake para exportar `div` como imágenes pero constantemente me sale un error:

> Uncaught Unrecognized document structure: {"_margin":null}

El código que tengo para esta parte lo dejo en el fiddle porque es muy largo:

https://jsfiddle.net/g726wnju/11/

No tengo muy claro si la estoy liando con el código porque ya le he dado mil vueltas. Aprecio cualquier ayuda o intento de la misma. Gracias¡

Comment: si probaste el código del jsfiddle? porque me dice que no existe la funcion "creategraph" y después me dice que no esta definido "AmCharts", podrías dejar un ejemplo funcional para ver si es posible ayudarte mejor?

Comment: si, el código no lo puse completo, solo la parte de la construcción del pdf por si existía algún error de código que fuera obvio, en cuanto tenga un momento actualizo el código para que sea funcional.